# Google App Engine PHP Include Error on deployed site

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have been working on a PHP site with the Google App Engine PHP SDK locally and everything works fine on my machine. I then deploy the site and it says it uploads successfully, however, when I view the hosted website the page is blank. When I check the log in the App Dashboard I get a number of Warnings and Errors:

```
PHP Warning:  include(): apc failed to locate includes/functions.php - bailing in /base/data/home/apps/s~raven3mil/1.373024475561310665/login.php on line 2

PHP Warning:  include(includes/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/apps/s~raven3mil/1.373024475561310665/login.php on line 2

PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'includes/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;/base/data/home/apps/s~raven3mil/1.373024475561310665/;/base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk') in /base/data/home/apps/s~raven3mil/1.373024475561310665/login.php on line 2

PHP Warning:  require_once(includes/session.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/apps/s~raven3mil/1.373024475561310665/login.php on line 3

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'includes/session.php' (include_path='.;/base/data/home/apps/s~raven3mil/1.373024475561310665/;/base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk') in /base/data/home/apps/s~raven3mil/1.373024475561310665/login.php on line 3

This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

Does anyone have any insight on the matter? I'm not sure where to go from here... Thanks!

UPDATE:

app.yaml

```
application: raven3mil
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /includes
  static_dir: includes

- url: /fullcalendar-1.6.2/fullcalendar
  static_dir: fullcalendar-1.6.2/fullcalendar

- url: /ckeditor
  static_dir: ckeditor

  # Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)
  script: \1

- url: /.*
  script: login.php

error_handlers:
- file: errors/404.php
```

The application names match and everything runs well locally.

Comment: What does your app.yaml file look like?

Comment: and what's the app_id ?

Comment: From the log output above it looks like his app id is raven3mil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default files in static file handlers cannot be read by your application unless you specify the [application_readable](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig) flag as part of the handler in the app.yaml, so you should change

```
- url: /includes
  static_dir: includes
```

to

```
- url: /includes
  static_dir: includes
  application_readable: true
```

Of course if you only have php scripts in this folder that you don't actually want to serve from your application but just want to deploy and access at runtime, then you should remove this handler all together. You do not need entries in the app.yaml file for the files to be uploaded with your application, only if you want then to be served in response to an incoming request.

Comment: This folder contains PHP scripts that are only to be included in other pages; they are not to be accessed individually.

Comment: Remove the handler altogether then.

Comment: The way the site was originally set up was to have anything that was to be included in a page in there. So my PHP, JS and CSS files are all in there. If I remove the handler the other files don't get included... I take it I should just separate them, right?

Comment: Yes you should only put content you want to serve in response to a request in a static_dir.

Answer (score 2):

The error can also be caused by the fact that on some operating systems (MAMP stack for example) is not case sensitive, but Jetty is (which GAE is built on). So if you are developing on an Apache stack and migrating to GAE,  you need to check that all your include paths are case sensitive.

Comment: +1 For checking case. We just had this issue and it's easily overlooked, especially if everything is working locally.

Comment: In my case google changed OAuth2.php to Oauth2.php which was hard to find